# startSlider() function of leaflet.timeSlider won't work and gives error

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm working with leaflet plugin leaflet.timeSlider.js. I've added the timeslider but it won't show a button to slide with. I've done everything is should i guess but i didn't add the startSlider() function because when i call it, it gives the error:

> leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_layerAdd' of
>   undefined
>           at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:5)
>           at e.startSlider (SliderControl.js:186)
>           at leafletmap.js:310

Here is some code i used.

```
var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
     layer: markersTemp,
     follow: true,
     range: true
});
map.addControl(sliderControl);
sliderControl.startSlider();
```

markersTemp is a layerGroup of markers. They all display fine on the map so i don't think the problem is there. Does anybody know what might be wrong?

Comment: Please specify the versions of Leaflet and Leaflet.timeSlider that you're currently usign.

Comment: leaflet 1.4.0 + i'm not using leaflet.timeslider anymore i'm now using a custom class sliderControl

Comment: I'm using this as an example: https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Here they use Geojson file with point, i have a normal json file with points but a different structure as a geojson file. Can you do it without geojson files or?